# LTSP installation problem

Tags: virtualization, ltsp, ltsp-client

On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I tried installing LTSP in "chroot" mode, following this [guide](http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Installation/Ubuntu).

The initial command

```
apt install --yes --install-recommends ltsp-server-standalone epoptes
```

Returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 epoptes : Depends: faketime but it is not installable
           Depends: iperf but it is not installable
           Depends: x11vnc but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: xterm but it is not installable
           Depends: xvnc4viewer but it is not installable or
                    tigervnc-viewer but it is not installable or
                    ssvnc but it is not installable or
                    vnc-viewer but it is not installable
           Recommends: epoptes-client but it is not going to be installed
 ltsp-server-standalone : Depends: ldm-server but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ltsp-server (>= 5.18.04+t201809080524~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: openbsd-inetd but it is not installable or
                                   inet-superserver but it is not installable
                          Recommends: ltsp-docs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My question is: how do I correct these broken packages, and also if I succeed in installing this system will I be able to emulate VMs using the CT-3000 Huawei thin client, which does not have ubuntu mate installed on it. I am also looking for info on how to install mate.

Comment: Just tested your installation command on fresh Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS VM. It succeded. So you need to enable *universe* repository (many packages are stored here).

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert you are exactly correct, enabling the universe repository facilitated a succesful installation. "will I be able to emulate VMs using the CT-3000 Huawei thin client, which does not have ubuntu mate installed on it" This part of the question still stands , I will be posting my documentation on what happens here. thanks again